# Query To Get "Most Recent" Joining On Other Table With Date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a couple of tables and need to join them, but with a twist.

Table #GradeChange has Student IDs, the Effective Date of the grade change, and the Grade they were changed to ON that date. Table #EventOccurrence has events that occurred for that student on a certain date. I need to find what grade the student was in when the event occurred. This will be the most recent Grade from #GradeChange that occurred prior to the #EventOccurrence Effective Date. Students may have multiple EventOccurrences, and we can assume all students will have at least one #GradeChange entry with a date prior to their oldest event.

This is the DDL:

```
    /* If the test table already exists, drop it */
     IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#GradeChange','U') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #GradeChange;

     IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#EventOccurrence','U') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #EventOccurrence;     

/* Create first temp table */ 
 CREATE TABLE #GradeChange 
        (
        ID varchar(6),
        EffectiveDate datetime,
        Grade varchar(50)
        );       

/* Populate it */        
INSERT INTO #GradeChange 
    (ID, EffectiveDate, Grade)
SELECT '678443','Jul  2 2009 11:30PM','Grade 3' UNION ALL
SELECT '678443','Jan 24 2007  2:40PM','Kindergarten - Half Day' UNION ALL
SELECT '678443','Jul  4 2007 11:09PM','Grade 1' UNION ALL
SELECT '678443','Jul  2 2008 11:35PM','Grade 2' UNION ALL
SELECT '718466','May 18 2009 11:50PM','Pre-Kindergarten' UNION ALL
SELECT '718466','Jul  2 2009 11:27PM','Kindergarten - Half Day' UNION ALL
SELECT '718466','Aug 27 2009 11:18PM','Pre-Kindergarten' UNION ALL
SELECT '718466','Jul  9 2010 11:18PM','Kindergarten - Half Day' UNION ALL
SELECT '718466','Aug  2 2010 11:14PM','Kindergarten';

/* Create 2nd temp table */
CREATE TABLE #EventOccurrence
    (
    ID varchar(6),
    EventDate datetime
    ); 

/* Populate it */
INSERT INTO #EventOccurrence
    (ID, EventDate)
SELECT '718466','Nov 16 2010 12:00AM' UNION ALL
SELECT '718466','May 20 2009 12:00AM' UNION ALL
SELECT '678443','Dec  7 2007 12:00AM';
```

So the two tables would look like this:

[image: Tables Example]

And the expected results would look like this:

[image: Results Example]

I've played with "MAX" and "MIN" and "OVER()" but can't quite get it right. I very much appreciate any help!

Comment: +1 for including DDL and sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select eo.ID, eo.EventDate, gc.Grade
    from #EventOccurrence eo
        inner join #GradeChange gc
            on eo.ID = gc.ID
                and gc.EffectiveDate = (select max(gc.EffectiveDate) 
                                            from #GradeChange gc 
                                            where gc.ID = eo.ID 
                                                and gc.EffectiveDate <= eo.EventDate)
```

Comment: This is probably the most intuitive answer, as I am not as familiar with MERGED and OUTER APPLY. It works, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    #EventOccurrence eo
OUTER APPLY
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 Grade
        FROM    #GradeChange gc
        WHERE   gc.id = eo.id
                AND gc.EffectiveDate <= eo.EventDate
        ORDER BY
                gc.EffectiveDate DESC
        ) gc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with merged (ID, DDate, Grade, pos) AS 
(
    select ID, DDate, Grade, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ID, DDate) AS pos FROM  (
        select ID, EffectiveDate AS DDate, Grade FROM GradeChange 
        union
        select ID, EventDate AS DDate, NULL FROM EventOccurrence 
    ) sub
) 
SELECT m1.ID, m1.DDate, m2.Grade FROM merged m1 LEFT OUTER JOIN merged m2 ON m1.pos = m2.pos+1 WHERE m1.Grade IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, PeeWee. Your answer was the first, and it works, so I selected it.  I very much appreciate all of your help!

Comment: @Daniel: note that it will return wrong results if there are two consecutive events without a grade change in between.

Comment: @Daniel: Check those time stamps again. This was actually the last of the 3 answers. :-)

Comment: @ Joe - HA, is it apparent I'm a newbie? I changed the accepted answer, but marked this one as useful. Thanks to all of you for your help!