# Get most recent event using JOIN

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, limit

I have 2 tables, for example:

Table1

```
ID,Name,Address1
```

Table2

```
Visit_date,item,id
```

Table 2 has lots of visits logged, and the id of the address.

I want to write a query that selects all Names and Addresses and their LAST visit date and item.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT ID, NAME, ADDRESS FROM table1) as temp 
RIGHT JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = temp.ID;
```

Is as far as I have gotten so far.

Comment: This is a special case of **Top N Per Group** where `n = 1`.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not 100% sure on how to construct that into my statement. I will have a go.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Query To Get "Most Recent" Joining On Other Table With Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830500/query-to-get-most-recent-joining-on-other-table-with-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a case for [cross-apply](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/796821b0-ba48-49b4-ba42-1783061d8c41/cross-apply-in-sqlserver?forum=transactsql)

```
select T1.ID, T1.Name, T1.Address1, T2.item, T2.Visit_date from
Table1 T1 cross apply (select top 1 * from Table2 where ID = Table1.ID 
order by     Visit_date desc) T2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER` in a CTE.

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t1.name, t1.address1, t2.Visit_date, t2.item, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t2.id ORDER BY t2.visit_date DESC) AS rn
FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN table1 t1
    ON t1.id = t2.id
)
SELECT name, address1, visit_date, item
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

[SQLFiddle proof](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6826f/9)